# How to join nested char array to string

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
def caesar_cipher(text, move_by)
    move_by %= 26
    chars = Hash[('a'..'z').map.with_index.to_a]
    converted = text.split.map do |word|
        word.chars.map do |char|
            if (chars[char.downcase] + move_by) <= 26
                chars.key(chars[char.downcase] + move_by)
            else
                chars.key(chars[char.downcase] + move_by - 26)
            end
        end
    end
end

print caesar_cipher("What a string", 5)
```

It converts string from variable `text` to integer. Here is the output I get when I run it: `[["b", "m", "f", "y"], ["f"], ["x", "y", "w", "n", "s", "l"]]`, and I'd like it to be joined like this`"bmft f xywnsl"`. I've tried `.join` method, but it gives me `"bmftfxywnsl"`

Comment: [Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) takes an argument that is the desired separator (defaults to no separation). You therefore need `join(' ')`.

Comment: Thanks for the greenie, but in future (or even now), consider waiting longer (at least a couple of hours, say) before selecting an answer. There's no rush. A quick selection can discourage other, sometimes better or just interesting, answers, and is not looked upon favourably by those still preparing their answers when they see the checkmark flash on out of the corner of their eye. Note you can always change the selection to a different answer (happens fairly often) or just retract the checkmark for the time being. Feel free to do either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If:

```
arr = [["b", "m", "f", "y"], ["f"], ["x", "y", "w", "n", "s", "l"]]
```

then

```
arr.map(&:join).join(' ')
  #=> "bmfy f xywnsl"
```

You can think of `map(&:join)` as:

```
arr.map { |a| a.join }.join(' ')
```

Isn't Ruby great?